Problema ao adicionar nova aba no editor de vendas - Primavera ERP V10 Extensibilidade
Estou a tentar adicionar uma nova aba no editor de vendas da minha aplicação, mas não estou conseguindo. O mesmo código funciona corretamente em outros contextos, como na ficha de clientes, mas no editor de vendas a aba não aparece ou não funciona como esperado.
Já tentei várias abordagens, incluindo seguir a documentação oficial, mas ainda não consegui resolver o problema. Gostaria de entender o que pode estar a acontecer.
Aqui está o código que estou a utilizar:
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Primavera.Extensibility.Base.Editors;
using Primavera.Extensibility.Sales.Editors;
using Primavera.Extensibility.Sales.Services;
using Primavera.Extensibility.CustomTab;

namespace Primavera.Base.CustomTabs
{
    // Classe que define o novo separador
    public partial class CustomerFields : CustomTab<FichaTabDocVendas>
    {
       
        public CustomerFields()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

       
        private void CustomerFields_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            AddControls();
        }

       
        private void AddControls()
        {
            
            TextBox textBox = new TextBox
            {
                Name = "MyTextBox",
                Text = "Olá, Mundo!",
                Width = 200,
                Height = 20,
                Top = 10,
                Left = 10
            };

            
            this.Controls.Add(textBox);

            
            Button button = new Button
            {
                Name = "MyButton",
                Text = "Clique aqui",
                Width = 100,
                Height = 30,
                Top = 40,
                Left = 10
            };

            button.Click += (s, e) => MessageBox.Show("Botão clicado!");

            this.Controls.Add(button);
        }
    }
}


Esta pergunta já foi postada e lá já foram fornecidas as orientações relevantes. Desta forma, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui para evitar descentralização de informações (mas continua disponível na postagem original, se restaurada).
